# How to share data between two Rails apps in both ways using rest-client in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

***Scenario:***

Let assume I have two Rails applications **App1** and **App2**. App2 fetches the data from App1 through [**rest-client**](https://github.com/rest-client/rest-client). Both the applications have almost common models and they use separate ***DBs***. Whenever a model attributes get updated in App1, they are fetched in App2.

***Goal:***

Now I need to do the ***reverse*** i.e, Whenever a model attributes get updated in ***App2***, they need to be fetched and updated in ***App1 DB***.

I couldn't able to find a way for doing this. Any help would be appreciated.

Below is the some basic code that involved in fetching the data from App1 to App2.

```
#app/controllers/application_controller.rb(App2)
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  # Prevent CSRF attacks by raising an exception.
  # For APIs, you may want to use :null_session instead.
  protect_from_forgery with: :exception
  before_filter :authenticate_user!

  require 'rest_client'

  App1_API_TOKEN = Rails.application.secrets[:app1_api_token] # needed to access the APi
  API_BASE_URL = Rails.application.secrets[:app1_base_api_url] # base url of the API
  FULL_AUTH_FIELD = "Token " + App1_API_TOKEN
  RENTERS_URI = "#{API_BASE_URL}/renters.json"
  OWNERS_URI = "#{API_BASE_URL}/owners.json"
  PROPERTIES_URI = "#{API_BASE_URL}/properties.json"
  OWNERS_REST_RESOURCE = RestClient::Resource.new(OWNERS_URI, :headers => {:Authorization => FULL_AUTH_FIELD})
  RENTERS_REST_RESOURCE = RestClient::Resource.new(RENTERS_URI, :headers => {:Authorization => FULL_AUTH_FIELD})
  PROPERTIES_REST_RESOURCE = RestClient::Resource.new(PROPERTIES_URI, :headers => {:Authorization => FULL_AUTH_FIELD})
  OWNERS = OWNERS_REST_RESOURCE.get
  RENTERS = RENTERS_REST_RESOURCE.get
  PROPERTIES = PROPERTIES_REST_RESOURCE.get
end
```

And one of the controllers code which uses the above defined constants.

```
#app/controller/premium_listings_controller.rb(App2)
class PremiumListingsController < ApplicationController
  # before_action :set_premium_listing, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]

  # GET /premium_listings
  # GET /premium_listings.json
  def index
    @owner = JSON.parse(OWNERS, :symbolize_names => true)
    @renter = JSON.parse(RENTERS, :symbolize_names => true)
    # TODO LOWP make this properites query filterable by status
    @premium_listings = JSON.parse(PROPERTIES, :symbolize_names => true)
  end

  # GET /premium_listings/1
  # GET /premium_listings/1.json
  def show
    property_uri = "#{API_BASE_URL}/properties/" + params[:id]
    property_rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new(property_uri, :headers => {:Authorization => FULL_AUTH_FIELD})
    property = property_rest_resource.get
    @premium_listing = JSON.parse(property, :symbolize_names => true)
  end

  # GET /premium_listings/new
  def new
    # TODO HIGHP needs to be connected through API to create NEW PROPERTY on ROORAH
    @premium_listing = PremiumListing.new
  end

  # GET /premium_listings/1/edit
  def edit
  end

  # POST /premium_listings
  # POST /premium_listings.json
  def create
    @premium_listing = PremiumListing.new(premium_listing_params)

    respond_to do |format|
      if @premium_listing.save
        format.html { redirect_to @premium_listing, notice: 'Premium listing was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @premium_listing }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @premium_listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # PATCH/PUT /premium_listings/1
  # PATCH/PUT /premium_listings/1.json
  def update
    respond_to do |format|
      if @premium_listing.update(premium_listing_params)
        format.html { redirect_to @premium_listing, notice: 'Premium listing was successfully updated.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @premium_listing }
      else
        format.html { render :edit }
        format.json { render json: @premium_listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end

  # DELETE /premium_listings/1
  # DELETE /premium_listings/1.json
  def destroy
    @premium_listing.destroy
    respond_to do |format|
      format.html { redirect_to premium_listings_url, notice: 'Premium listing was successfully destroyed.' }
      format.json { head :no_content }
    end
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_premium_listing
      @premium_listing = PremiumListing.find(params[:id])
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def premium_listing_params
      params[:premium_listing]
    end
end
```

Comment: This code doesn't fetch data from App1 and store it in App2 DB. It just sends requests to App1 and returns responses in App1 controllers. But new PremiumListings are created in App2 DB, not in App1 DB. So you need to synchronize PremiumListings between the two DBs?

Comment: @Jeiwan I think this line `@premium_listings = JSON.parse(PROPERTIES, :symbolize_names => true)` in the `index` action of the `premium_listings_controller` fetches the Json data form App1. And yes whenever a premium_listing gets updated in App2, I need to update it in App1 DB as well.

Comment: @Jeiwan You are right. The data from App1 doesn't store in App2 DB. It just shows the data in App2.

Comment: Yep, you're right. It fetches the data, but doesn't store it in App2 DB. The question is: do you really need to store new listings in App1 DB? I think you can modify index action to return both App1 and App2 listings.

Comment: @Jeiwan I don't want to store the new listings in App1 DB, but I need to update the listings in App1 DB whenever a listing is updated in App2.

Comment: But you can't update App1 listings from App2, because they don't exist in App2 DB. The controller code seems to not be finished. It displays listings from App1 but creates new ones in App2. So, new listings will never be shown. Do you really need new listings to be created in App2 DB? Or instead you want to create them in App1 DB through the web-interface of App2?

Comment: The question is not clear. I see two possibilities here: 1. Create new listings in App2 DB and sync them to App1. The same goes for updates. 2. Create new listings in App1 DB but using App2 web-interface. So App2 is kinda frontend-client for App1 and it doesn't store anything in its DB.

Comment: @Jeiwan Sorry for the confusion. Forget about the new listings. The existing listings in App1 DB are displayed in App2 but not created in App2 DB unless they are updated in App2. So while updating that particular existing listing in App2, I want to update it in App1 DB as well. Hope I make it clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So App2 is kinda front-end app for App1. To update App1 records from App2 you need to rewrite `update` action in `PremiumListingsController`. It shouldn't update listings in App2 DB, but instead it should send `PUT` request to App1 with current listing properties. After getting a response it should redirect to `@premium_listing` with success message or render `show` with error message (this is what it does now).

It should look like so:

```
def update
  property_uri = "#{API_BASE_URL}/properties/" + params[:id]
  property_rest_resource = RestClient::Resource.new(property_uri, :headers => {:Authorization => FULL_AUTH_FIELD})
  property_rest_resource.put(premium_listing_params)
  format.html { redirect_to @premium_listing, notice: 'Premium listing was successfully updated.' }
  format.json { render :show, status: :ok, location: @premium_listing }
rescue => e
  format.html { render :edit }
  format.json { render json: @premium_listing.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
end
```

(This is just a sketch to demonstrate the idea, not sure if it works)

App1 should have `update` action for `/properties/:id` url. This action takes parameters, updates the listing in DB and returns `200/204` code for success or `4**` code for errors. RestClient raises an exception when response code is not `2**`.

Comment: With a slight modification, your answer worked. Thank you! :)